# Is it always possible to choose a family of connected coordinate neighborhoods to cover a regular surface?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Despite the title, I'm actually dealing with the proof of the criterion concerning orientability of a regular surface. Here is the proposition to be proved:

[image]

As the red circle indicates, do Carmo, the author, used connectedness to prove the sufficiency. What if $S$ cannot be covered with a family of connected coordinate neighborhoods? Maybe I should paste the definition of a regular surface:

[image]

$\mathbf{X}(U)$ is the so-called coordinate neighborhood at $p$. Thanks.

Comment: If it can be covered by open sets, it can be covered by connected open sets (just take all the connected components of a given open set as different elements of the open covering).

Comment: I still can't get it. Is there any theorem in Munkres' $\textit{Topology}$ that establishes the result? Thank you.

Comment: Read Munkres's section on connected components. Notice that for manifolds connectedness and path-connectedness are the same notion, so perhaps path-connectedness will be more intuitive for you.

Comment: @Wombat Maybe you should read about how homeomorphism preserves connectivity and how open sets in Euclidean space can be decomposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any coordinate neighborhood of $p \in S$ comes along with a map $x : U \to V \cap S$ as in your definition. Now let $p' = x^{-1}(p)$. Since $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$, there exists an open disk $U' = U(p',r)  = \{ q \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \lVert q - p' \rVert < r \}$ which is contained in $U$. This is a connected set (it is even path connected). Since $x$ is a homeomorphism, $x(U')$ is open in $V \cap S$. Hence there exists an open $V' \subset \mathbb R^3$ such that $V' \cap S = x(U')$. Then define $x' : U' \to V' \cap S$ as the restricton of $x$. It is obviuos that properties 1. - 3. are satisfied. That is, we found a connected coordinate neighborhood $x'(U')$ around $p$.

Comment: Did you use the fact that continuity preserves connectedness? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but in this case $U'$ and $x(U')$ are even *homeomorphic*.

Comment: Sir, I have one more question. If you have free time, please take a look. Thank you. [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312575/a-regular-surface-s-is-orientable-iff-there-exists-a-differentiable-field-of-u)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard argument in Topology. Suppose $x(u,v): U \to S$ is one local parametrization of $S$. It is by definition that $x$ is a local diffeomorphism from $U$ to $x(U)$. Because $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set, hence it is a union of open balls , say $\bigcup B_{r}$ (these open balls may have intersection but it's fine).

Since each open ball $B_r$ is connected (more precisely, path-connected), hence $x\vert_{B_r}$ is a diffeomorphism from $B_r$ to $S$. If we decompose the map $x$ to its restriction to all such $B_r$, then all such restrictions are diffeomorphism, covering the same surface patch as $x$, and at the same time, having connected domain.

Therefore it is W.L.O.G. to assume all members in the family of parametrization have connected domain and thus, they are mapping connected domains to connected neighbourhoods.