# A regular surface $S$ is orientable iff there exists a differentiable field of unit normal vectors on $S$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Here is a proposition quoted from the book written by do Carmo. I don't understand the part underlined with red. Or equivalently (I guess), I don't know how it works to make sure that the given field $N$ is, on every coordinate neighborhood, compatible with the family of connected coordinate neighborhood. By compatibility, I mean
>   $$N=\frac{X_u\wedge X_v}{|X_u\wedge X_v|},$$
>   where $X$ is a parametrization of a coordinate neighborhood in the family. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

> One may not know the definition of the change of coordinates. It is simply the transition map between two overlapping surface patches. But more information is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interchanging $u$ and $v$ means the following: You have a chart $x : U \to V \cap S, (u,v) \mapsto x(u,v)$. Now consider the homeomorphism $\tau : \mathbb R^2  \to \mathbb R^2, \tau(u,v) = (v,u)$. Note $\tau \circ \tau = id$. Then $x' : \tau(U) \stackrel{\tau}{\rightarrow} U \stackrel{x}{\rightarrow} V \cap S$ is a new chart in which $(u,v) \mapsto x(v,u)$. Both charts parametrize the same coordinate neigborhood $V \cap S$.

The idea is to start with *any* family of charts having *connected* coordinate neighborhoods. Connectedness assures that for all $(u,v)$ either $N=\frac{x_u\wedge x_v}{|x_u\wedge x_v|}$ or $N=-\frac{x_u\wedge x_v}{|x_u\wedge x_v|}$. In the second case use the above method to replace
the original chart by the "switched" chart. Thus the field $N$ is used to find a new family of charts which is "normalized" by the condition $N=\frac{x_u\wedge x_v}{|x_u\wedge x_v|}$.

Comment: One last ride: Is $$x'_u(u,v)=x_v(v,u)?$$ Thank you.

Comment: Yes. If you interchange $u$ and $v$, then $x'_u = x_v$.

Answer (score 2):

In every coorditanete neighbourheed, there are two possibilities. Or

$$N=\frac{X_u\wedge X_v}{|X_u\wedge X_v|},$$

or
$$N=-\frac{X_u\wedge X_v}{|X_u\wedge X_v|}. $$

Note that, in each neighbourhood only one of those options can occur, by the argument do Carmo gives in the following paragraph.

If the first possibility occurs, do nothing. If the second occurs, reparametrize that neighbourhood with the parametrization:
$$\hat{X}(u,v)=X(v,u).$$

Then, you have:
$$N=-\frac{X_u\wedge X_v}{|X_u\wedge X_v|}=\frac{\hat{X}_u\wedge \hat{X}_v}{|\hat{X}_u\wedge \hat{X}_v|}.$$

What do Carmo is saying is that, WLOG, you can assume you have already done the necessary reparametrizations.

Comment: In fact, I have thought of this. However, for $\hat{X}(u,v)$ to be well-defined, the pair $(v,u)$ must lie in the domain of $X$, which is what I am worried about. Thank you.

Comment: OK, here is an idea. Let $$W=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2:(v,u)\in U\}$$ and let $\phi:W\rightarrow U$ be defined by $\phi(u,v)=(v,u)$. How do I prove that $W$ is open? If so, $X\circ\phi$ will be the desired parametrization.

Comment: I have known $W$ is an open set.

Comment: The only thig you are doing is to rename the variables.